# Excel VBA Select Item in Multi Column ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combobox that gets populated with information sourced from an Access Database. I have a method that opens up records using a ADO Recordset. I have a multicolumn combobox that I want to select a value from the populated list on the form. For single column combobox's, the value that gets shown on the form is populated using the value property as shown below.

```
 frmDataEntry.txtProcessID = sourceRS.Fields("ProcessID").Value
```

I am having issues populating a multicolumn combobox as the Value property does not work.

```
Do Until y >= frmDataEntry.cmbProcess.listCount
     If frmDataEntry.cmbProcess.List(y, 0) = sourceRS.Fields("ProcessID").Value Then
        'This is where i'd like to set the value
    End If
    y = y + 1
Loop
```

In the code above, if this were a listbox, i would use `.Selected(y) = True` property but that is not available for comboboxes. Does anybody have any suggestions? I have searched everywhere but cannot seem to find a way to do this without wiping out the populated list of the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if your problem is displaying an *already added* value, `frmDataEntry.cmbProcess.ListIndex = y` will do exactly that for `0 <= y < ListCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is what I do. I put the values into an array then do this:

```
Dim MyArray() As String 
'Here you want to populate MyArray
With Me.combobox1 
    .ColumnCount = 2 
    .BoundColumn = 2 
    .ColumnWidths = "2.5 in; 0 in" 
    .List = MyArray 
End With
```